# Flutter Launcher icon doesn't change the icon

Tags: flutter

[image: sample code]

I already type this to my terminal and the icon for my app didn't change

flutter pub get

flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've set the app icon path in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Comment: android:icon="@mipmap/icon_launcher">
this is my code in the manifest.xml

is there any error in what I've done?

Comment: The icons are generated in `android\app\src\main\res\mipmap`. Could you tell me what's the image file's name in `mipmap-hdpi`.

Comment: ic_launcher.png thats the images files

Comment: Then change it to `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

Comment: It still didn't work.

Comment: Weird. Did you try a `flutter clean`?

Comment: Yes, I already tried it. Yeah its weird.

Answer (score -2):

Try below code hope its help to you.

Add below package in your pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
```

Add below code pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icon.png" 
  android: true
  ios: true
```

then run below command

```
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Comment: this is my original code and nothing happens. The icon didn't change